# cakephp 3 order by query generates 14 queries with associate tables instead of 1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My cakephp3 app works very well and now I wish to order some of the queries by the associated table fields.

The query works fine when ordered by a field in the current model. But if I choose to order by a field `Models.field` in an associated table I now get 14 sql queries rather than the one. But the real problem is that the `ORDER BY` is not included in the query.

I am in the CoursesEmployees model which has employee_id and course_id fields.

CoursesEmployeesController.php

```
public function certificate() {
    $this->paginate = [
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Employees.surname', 'Courses.name', 'date_completed'
        ],
        'conditions' => ['CoursesEmployees.completed' => true, 'Employees.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')],
        'contain' => ['Employees', 'Courses'],
        'order' => ['Employees.name'=>'asc']
    ];
    $this->set('coursesEmployees', $this->paginate($this->CoursesEmployees));
}
```

If I order by `'order' => ['date_created'=>'asc']` I get one query and all works fine.

```
SELECT
    CoursesEmployees.id AS `CoursesEmployees__id`,
    CoursesEmployees.employee_id AS `CoursesEmployees__employee_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.course_id AS `CoursesEmployees__course_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.course_module_id AS `CoursesEmployees__course_module_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.cid AS `CoursesEmployees__cid`,
    CoursesEmployees.progress AS `CoursesEmployees__progress`,
    CoursesEmployees.modified AS `CoursesEmployees__modified`,
    CoursesEmployees.created AS `CoursesEmployees__created`,
    CoursesEmployees.completed AS `CoursesEmployees__completed`,
    CoursesEmployees.date_completed AS `CoursesEmployees__date_completed`,
    Employees.id AS `Employees__id`,
    Employees.user_id AS `Employees__user_id`,
    Employees.hotel_id AS `Employees__hotel_id`,
    Employees.name AS `Employees__name`,
    Employees.email AS `Employees__email`,
    Employees.surname AS `Employees__surname`,
    Employees.employee_num AS `Employees__employee_num`,
    Employees.modified AS `Employees__modified`,
    Employees.created AS `Employees__created`,
    Courses.id AS `Courses__id`,
    Courses.name AS `Courses__name`,
    Courses.course_lenght AS `Courses__course_lenght` 
FROM
    courses_employees CoursesEmployees 
INNER JOIN
    employees Employees 
        ON Employees.id = (
            CoursesEmployees.employee_id
        ) 
INNER JOIN
    courses Courses 
        ON Courses.id = (
            CoursesEmployees.course_id
        ) 
WHERE
    (
        CoursesEmployees.completed = 1 
        AND Employees.user_id = '1'
    ) 
ORDER BY
    CoursesEmployees.date_completed asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

If I `'order' => ['Employees.name'=>'asc']`(or any random text for the field name) I get 14 sql queries and the main query does not have the order at the end as it should.

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `courses_employees`  10  1

SHOW INDEXES FROM `courses_employees`   1   0

SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc ON (kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'deep_mind' AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = 'courses_employees' and rc.TABLE_NAME = 'courses_employees'    0   0

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'courses_employees'  1   0

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `employees`  9   1

SHOW INDEXES FROM `employees`   1   0

SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc ON (kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'deep_mind' AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = 'employees' and rc.TABLE_NAME = 'employees'    0   0

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'employees'  1   0

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `courses`    3   1

SHOW INDEXES FROM `courses` 1   0

SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc ON (kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'deep_mind' AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = 'courses' and rc.TABLE_NAME = 'courses'    0   0

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'courses'    1   0

SELECT
    CoursesEmployees.id AS `CoursesEmployees__id`,
    CoursesEmployees.employee_id AS `CoursesEmployees__employee_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.course_id AS `CoursesEmployees__course_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.course_module_id AS `CoursesEmployees__course_module_id`,
    CoursesEmployees.cid AS `CoursesEmployees__cid`,
    CoursesEmployees.progress AS `CoursesEmployees__progress`,
    CoursesEmployees.modified AS `CoursesEmployees__modified`,
    CoursesEmployees.created AS `CoursesEmployees__created`,
    CoursesEmployees.completed AS `CoursesEmployees__completed`,
    CoursesEmployees.date_completed AS `CoursesEmployees__date_completed`,
    Employees.id AS `Employees__id`,
    Employees.user_id AS `Employees__user_id`,
    Employees.hotel_id AS `Employees__hotel_id`,
    Employees.name AS `Employees__name`,
    Employees.email AS `Employees__email`,
    Employees.surname AS `Employees__surname`,
    Employees.employee_num AS `Employees__employee_num`,
    Employees.modified AS `Employees__modified`,
    Employees.created AS `Employees__created`,
    Courses.id AS `Courses__id`,
    Courses.name AS `Courses__name`,
    Courses.course_lenght AS `Courses__course_lenght` 
FROM
    courses_employees CoursesEmployees 
INNER JOIN
    employees Employees 
        ON Employees.id = (
            CoursesEmployees.employee_id
        ) 
INNER JOIN
    courses Courses 
        ON Courses.id = (
            CoursesEmployees.course_id
        ) 
WHERE
    (
        CoursesEmployees.completed = 1 
        AND Employees.user_id = '1'
    ) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: The extra queries are not relevant to your order-by question. `(or any random text for the field name` - that sounds like order by whitelisting being the reason - which was [modified recently](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6725). Please clean up the question to focus on "the problem" and clarify that it is pagination-specific, the title and body of the question is quite misleading at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-run the script immediately, you should see those queries disappearing.

These queries are being used to grab data for generating schemas and other metadata, and by default this should happen rather rarely as the data is being cached, given that `cacheMetadata` is enabled in your apps datasource configuration.

By default the data is being cached for 2 minutes, check your apps cache config for `_cake_model_`. This is the value that is going to be used when the app is running in debug mode. When not in debug mode, the duration is  by default being set to 1 year, check your apps `boostrap.php`.

See also

- **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/config/app.default.php#L117**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/config/bootstrap.php#L87-L93**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Metadata Caching](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-metadata-cache)**
- **[Cookbook  > Database Access & ORM > ORM Cache Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/orm-cache.html)**

---

As for your missing order field problem, you are missing the `Employees.name` field in your whitelisting, however even when whitelisting fields of other models it doesn't seem to work.

That seems to be a bug in the paginator, namely in the `PaginatorComponent::_prefix()` method, where the field is being swallowed, finally resulting in an empty `order` option being passed to the query.

Looks like this has already been reported and [**fixed**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6740) for the upcoming 3.0.7 release. If you can't wait, grab the master branch or apply the patch.

Comment: Great thanks for the insight :-) When I re-run the script indeed only one query. If I switch the field name to order by, the multiple queries appear again on the first load. However my problem remains if I use the Models.field I do not get `order by` in the query. I just get `LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

Comment: @KeithPower I have to admin that I only skimmed through the text, I'll have another look on your question in a momet.

Comment: Thanks, I might have confused the problem by mentioning the extra queries rather than the `order by` is missing form the query on associated table

Comment: Just a small note, if I take the query and add the `ORDER BY Employees.name` to the end  and run the sql directly in the database I get the expected results.

Comment: @KeithPower I've updated my answer, AFAICT the missing order seems to be a bug.

Comment: @KeithPower Ah, wait, there is probably a bug, but you're also missing the necessary whitelisting.

Comment: Sorry I do have `Employees.name` in the whitelist in my code. The problem remains when using anything in the whitelist.

Comment: @KeithPower Yep, that is to be expected. I've updated my answer again with a link to the fix.

Comment: I have updated to dev-master and verified it included the fix for #6740. But unfortunately I still do not get the `ORDER BY` in the query. I have made sure my whitelist matches

Comment: The update has fixed a related issue with `$this->Paginator->sort('Employees.surname', 'STAFF NAME')` with associated table. That now works.

Comment: @KeithPower So your problem is fixed now, or are you referring to something different? (we're talking about the default ordering, not the order that is being applied after changing it in the rendered view, right?) I can't really see anything obvious that would cause further problems, I've tried the master branch and the problem is gone, the order appears as expected.

Comment: Yes you are right. The issue is resolved, I pulled back some changes I had made and I now have the `ORDER BY`. Thanks.